# Query to update records using sum of fields and conditional

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to look at all of the records in a table and if the sum of some columns (HandleTime, HoldTime, NotReadyTime) is greater than another column (LoggedTime) then set that column to the sum.

Basically this, extended for the whole table, but as an SQL query in the database:

```
If Sum(HandleTime,HoldTime,NotReadyTime) > LoggedTime then
    LoggedTime = Sum(HandleTime,HoldTime,NotReadyTime)
End if
```

Not sure whether to use a SELECT or UPDATE query, or how to utilise the sum. I think it might be DSUM? I tried both but returned empty fields.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean :

```
update yourtable
set LoggedTime = HandleTime + HoldTime + NotReadyTime
where HandleTime + HoldTime + NotReadyTime > LoggedTime
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a table with calculated values, that's what queries are for. Like this:

```
Select 
    *,
    IIf(LoggedTime > HandleTime + HoldTime + NotReadyTime, LoggedTime, HandleTime + HoldTime + NotReadyTime) As TotalTime
From
    YourTable
```

Comment: I agree, Gustav. However, this isnt a calculated value, the Logged time can be larger than the Sum but it shouldnt be less than and due to an error in the data source it has come through as less, in some cases. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Oh, that you didn't mention.